# @Value не подтягивает значения

Tags: java, spring-boot

В конфиг классе @Value не подтягивает значения из проверти файла

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties")
public class BotConfig {

    @Value("${bot.name}")
    String name;

    @Value("${bot.token}")
    String token;

}
```

Bot:

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final BotConfig CONFIG = new BotConfig();
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать `classpath:application.properties`.

Comment: Пробовал, не вышло

Comment: Тогда нужно больше информации. Структура проекта, содержимое пропертис-файла и место, где вы запрашиваете данный бин.

Comment: Добавил, по структуре я пробовал выносить конфиг файл в основной пакет - не помогает. Думал может проблема с подключением botConnect() и пытался выводить имя и токен через System.out.println - выводит null

Comment: Ну, на самом деле очень странно выглядит создание каких-либо объектов после вызова метода `run` в Spring Boot. Плюс к этом, вы сами создаёте объект от `Bot`, а это, наверно, тоже бин, поэтому этим должен заниматься сам Spring. Далее, вы хотите подтянуть зависимости в `BotConfig`, а в приведённом коде они ни в каких методах не используется, поэтому ошибку не понять. Пока что я могу посоветовать не использовать Spring Boot только ради его метода `run` (который в вашем случае, видимо, лишний), а использовать просто Spring Framework для внедрения зависимостей, что вы, видимо, и хотите.

Comment: Правильней будет видимо запустить botConnect() аннотацией @PostConstruct?

Comment: Добавил BotInitializer, в мейне ничего не создаю, ошибка не ушла.:(
Кто-нибудь знает как работает @EventListener?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что сам создавал объект поля BotConfig. Если пишешь на Spring - все объекты должны быть созданы им.

Было:

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final BotConfig CONFIG = new BotConfig();
}
```

Стало:

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final BotConfig CONFIG;

    @Autowired
    public Bot(BotConfig config) {
        CONFIG = config;
    }
```